# SQL query construction: checking if query result is subset of another

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

Hi Guys I have a table relation which works like this (legacy)

A has many B and B has many C;
A has many C as well

Now I am having trouble coming up with a SQL which will help me to get all B (Id of B to make it simple) mapped to certain A(by Id) AND any B which has a collection of C that's a subset of Cs of that A.

I have failed to come up with a decent sql specially for the second part and was wondering if I can get any tips / suggestions re how I can do that.

Thanks

EDIT:

```
Table A

Id     |..
------------
 1     |..




Table B

Id     |..
--------------
2      |..

Table A_B_rel 

A_id  |    B_id
-----------------
1     |     2
```

C is a strange table. The data of C (single column) is actually just duped in 2 rel table for A and B. so its like this

```
Table B_C_Table

B_Id| C_Value
-----------------
2   | 'Somevalue' 

Table A_C_Table

A_Id| C_Value
-------------
1   |    'SomeValue'
```

So I am looking for Bs the C_Values of which are subset of certain A_C_Values.

Comment: maybe you can give an example? a few rows in each table would do, try http://sqlfiddle.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the second part of your problem is a bit tricky. We've got `B_C_Table` on the one hand, and a subset of `A_C_Table` where `A_ID` is a specific ID, on the other.

Now, if we use an outer join, we'll be able to see which rows in `B_C_Table` have no match in `A_C_Table`:

```
SELECT *
FROM B_C_Table bc
  LEFT JOIN A_C_Table ac ON bc.C_Value = ac.C_Value AND ac.A_ID = @A_ID
```

Note that it is important to put the `ac.A_ID = @A_ID` into the `ON` clause rather than into `WHERE`, because in the latter case we would be filtering out non-matching rows of `@A_ID`, which is not what we want.

The next step (to achieving the final query) would be to group rows by `B` and count rows. Now, we will calculate both the total number of rows and the number of *matching* rows.

```
SELECT
  bc.B_ID,
  COUNT(*)       AS TotalCount,
  COUNT(ac.A_ID) AS MatchCount
FROM B_C_Table bc
  LEFT JOIN A_C_Table ac ON bc.C_Value = ac.C_Value AND ac.A_ID = @A_ID
GROUP BY bc.B_ID
```

As you can see, to count matches, we simply count `ac.A_ID` values: in case of no match the corresponding column will be `NULL` and thus not counted. And if indeed some rows in `B_C_Table` do not match any rows in the subset of `A_C_Table`, we will see *different* values of `TotalCount` and `MatchCount`.

And that logically leads us towards the final step: *comparing* those counts. (For, obviously, if we can obtain values, we can also compare them.) But not in the `WHERE` clause, of course, because aggregate functions aren't allowed in `WHERE`. It's the `HAVING` clause that is used to compare values of *grouped* rows, including aggregated values too. So...

```
SELECT
  bc.B_ID,
  COUNT(*)       AS TotalCount,
  COUNT(ac.A_ID) AS MatchCount
FROM B_C_Table bc
  LEFT JOIN A_C_Table ac ON bc.C_Value = ac.C_Value AND ac.A_ID = @A_ID
GROUP BY bc.B_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(ac.A_ID)
```

The count values aren't really needed, of course, and when you drop them you will be able to UNION the above query with the one selecting `B_ID` from `A_B_rel`:

```
SELECT B_ID
FROM A_B_rel
WHERE A_ID = @A_ID

UNION

SELECT bc.B_ID
FROM B_C_Table bc
  LEFT JOIN A_C_Table ac ON bc.C_Value = ac.C_Value AND ac.A_ID = @A_ID
GROUP BY bc.B_ID
HAVING COUNT(*) = COUNT(ac.A_ID)
```

Comment: Thanks for the amazing explanations and comprehensive answer +1 as well for that.

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps this is what you're looking for:

```
SELECT B_id
FROM A_B_rel
WHERE A_id = <A ID>

UNION

SELECT a.B_Id
FROM B_C_Table a
LEFT JOIN A_C_Table b ON a.C_Value = b.C_Value AND b.A_Id = <A ID>
GROUP BY a.B_Id
HAVING COUNT(CASE WHEN b.A_Id IS NULL THEN 1 END) = 0
```

The first `SELECT` gets all `B`'s which are mapped to a particular `A` (`<A ID>` being the input parameter for the A ID), then we tack onto that result set any additional `B`'s whose *entire* set of `C_Value`'s are **within** the subset of the `C_Value`'s of the particular `A` (again, `<A ID>` being the input parameter).

Comment: First part of your query is fine. Second one is partially correct and that's where the problem is..in your case if any C_Value from A_C_Table matches that of B_C_table then its true but my scenario is "all" not "any". So I only need B_Id for those B's whose C_Values are a subset of the A's C_Values. So is A_C_Value is {0, 1, 2, 3} and B_C_Values {0, 1, 2, 9} then its not a match. But if B_C_Value is {1, 3} or {0, 2, 3} etc then I want this B and so on.

Comment: @user446923 I literally just got back, I'm taking a look right now.

Comment: +1 for the answer. I have accepted Andriy M's answer for being comprehensive but thanks heaps for yours as well!

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like you need to think in terms of double negation, i.e. there should not exist any B_C that does not have a matching A_C (and I'm guessing there should be at least one B_C).

So, try something like

```
select B.B_id
from Table_B B 
where exists (select 1 from B_C_Table BC
                  where BC.B_id = B.B_id)
  and not exists (select 1 from B_C_Table BC
                  where BC.B_id = B.B_id
                    and not exists(select 1 from B_C_Table AC
                                   join A_B_Rel ABR on AC.A_id = ABR.A_id
                                   where ABR.B_id = B.B_id
                                     and BC.C_Value = AC.C_Value))
```